# Remove space in a file efficiently

Tags: bash, perl, awk, replace, sed

I have a very big file and I want to remove the space character in the file.

The 'sed' can be used but it is very slow.

Is there any command that can use `fixed string` instead of `regex`to replace or remove space.

Comment: `tr -d ' '` not work ?

Comment: The close vote chosen was “Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.” It is perhaps not terribly off-topic, since you’re asking about general Unix tools, but SO is more about programming; this question would be a better fit on Unix/Linux or SuperUser.

Comment: How big is *"huge"*?

Comment: @TomZych, since the OP has tagged Perl as a possible solution I would disagree that it should be closed or moved.

Comment: @md4: I probably should have clarified that it wasn't my close vote. But I can see how the voter was thinking. If it's a general tool question, it's a better fit on U/L or SU. If it's a programming question, then where's the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tr` command (see manpage for more information):

```
cat filename | tr -d "\t\n\r"
```

It has option to define character class also. Eg:

To delete all whitespace:

```
cat filename | tr -d "[:space:]"
```

To delete all horizontal whitespace:

```
cat filename | tr -d "[:blank:]"
```

Comment: Or, more succinctly, `tr -d '...' < filename`

Comment: `sed` takes `2m9.665s` and `tr` takes` 0m3.301s`!

Comment: Perl is very fast in such things too: `perl -pe 's/\s//g' file` but I think nothing can beat `tr`.

Comment: it wouldn't beat `tr` but Perl also has tr that is faster than `s//`.  `perl -pe 'tr/ //d' file`